# How can I change user and keep my .profile

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, su

I often have to work as `root` (using `sudo`), but I want to keep my settings from my login profile - I have had this working in the past, but I don't quite remember how I made it work. This is what I've got to, so far:

```
db3 $ sudo su -c "bash --init-file /home/jan/.bashrc"
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
db3 $ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

My testing shows that my profile has been run, but I want to resolve the errors listed above. As I recall, it involves forcing one of the commands, `sudo`, `su` or `bash` to create (?) a tty (?). However, I can't find an option to do this, and it may be that I get the combination of commands wrong. Has anybody solved this?

Comment: Why are you actually using `su -c` here?

Comment: I want to get bash to run a specific profile, rather than the one that is defined for root

Comment: Yeah but that's already done by `--init-file`, and the su -c does nothing at all

Comment: `sudo bash --init-file /home/jan/.bashrc`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That was it! I was complicating it - I mixed it up with a similar problem, where I wanted to log as root in using ssh, but using my normal profile - ssh has an option to force pty allocation. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: You write an answer. I just made grawity's point clearer.

Comment: If you wish - I just thought you should harvest a few point :-)

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to @grawity and @KamilMaciorowski, here's an answer to make it easier to find for others. I had mixed it up with a different problem (see my comment under the OP) - it is in fact very simple:

```
sudo bash --init-file /home/jan/.bashrc
```